# Render bokeh control inside bootstrap carousel

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bokeh

I've got a bokeh plot in a bootstrap carousel, but the bokeh controls show to the right of the carousel control.  Without bootstrap carousel, the bokeh plot renders as desired with the bokeh controls flush right to the plot.

How can I force the bokeh controls to be inside the carousel inner, flush right to the plot?

Here is a screenshot showing the bokeh controls in the top right (with red rectangles and arrows overlain showing where I expect the controls to be):

[image]

Here is an example:

http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/jdimatteo/flask_bokeh_app/blob/carousel/bokeh_carousel.html

A fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ddrh3tx9/

Here is the carousel inner:

```
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <div class="item active" align="center">
                <h1>1</h1>
                <div class="bk-root">
                    <div class="plotdiv" id="327a612d-5699-4f1e-80bb-5acab5228f0a"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item" align="center">
                <h1>2</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: I don't know this library, but maybe it will be faster if you create a fiddle reproducing your issue.

Comment: I added a reproducing fiddle into the question, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*One way is to add this :*

**CSS**:

```
.bk-toolbar-wrapper.bk-layout-null{
      left: 100% !important;
      position: absolute;
}
```

**Fiddle** : https://jsfiddle.net/znqwu0c0/

---

Depending of screen size, sometimes, bokeh controls can be under the carousel controls, so in order to still make them clickable, you can add this to your carousel-inner class :

**CSS**

```
.carousel-inner{z-index: 1000;}
```

**Fiddle** : https://jsfiddle.net/znqwu0c0/1/

Comment: thanks, I didn't know about z-index and I'm reading up on css position.  your fiddle suggestion was great too.  I'm just ramping up on web development

Comment: I've check your github repo, don't hesitate to ask help.